# Kronecker delta for inequality

Tags: notation, kronecker-delta

Kronecker delta return 1, or 0 depending on a conditional statement (if $i = j$), for example, $\delta_{i,j} = 1$ if $i = j$, and $\delta_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise. I would like to know if there are conventional symbols for similar expressions with conditional statements such as (if $i \lt j$) and (if $i\leq j$)?

For instance, a conventional symbol for $X$ in the following expression: $X_{i,j} = 0$ if $i \lt j$, and $X_{i,j} = 1$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by talking about the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $[p]$, which for a claim $p$ is equal to $1$ if $p$ is true or $0$ if $p$ is false. Thus $\delta_{ij}=[i=j]$, while your $X_{ij}$ is $[i\ge j]$. I'm unaware of any other notation you could use (except, say, $\sum_{k\ge j}\delta_{ik}$ or $\sum_{k\le i}\delta_{jk}$).

Comment: @ J.G. Thanks again for pointing out the concept of the Iverson bracket. In Mathematica this corresponds to the function Boole[cond]. I have seen some discussion of how to typewrite Iverson brackets in LaTEX. Since we already have a lot of brackets I suggest to extend the notation of Kronecker delta to $\delta_{cond}$, e.g. $\delta_{i=j}$, $\delta_{i>j}$ or $\delta_{i \in \text{even}}$ etc. What do you think?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze The use of square brackets is the only option I've ever seen. I'd love a link to any online discussion of alternatives. I suppose an author could put a subscript on the closing bracket, if they explain in that context that it indicates an Iverson bracket. I'm not sure about your $\delta$ proposal; the Kronecker delta is already a special case. Writing $\delta_{i=j}$, which is equivalent to $\delta_{ij}$, looks especially silly. More generally, if we identify true/false with $1$/$0$, $\delta_{cond}$ is $\delta_{cond\,1}$.

Comment: @ J.G. More precisely my proposal means that $\delta_{\text{true}}=1$ and $\delta_{\text{false}}=1$. I have made my proposal also here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297752/a-method-of-distinguishing-iverson-from-other-brackets/522442#522442